# similar of my posts in all over the internet sites and blogs

Tags: plugins, customization, tooltip

i asked here in WordPress first and next asked [there](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/42987/21250) in webmasters Stack but i think here is very useful for WordPress users but close my question.

I'm using the similar posts plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/similar-posts/, but I want the similar posts in all over the internet.

is there any tools that when someone copy and paste my article in their own site alert to me?

some of the bloggers don't link to my articles and i want to

Comment: Your question is general and not specific to wordpress. Sidenote: you can't prevent people from copying your content and you probably can't stop them without having expensive lawyers all over the world.

Comment: i dont want to prevent people but i want to know when and who copy them ...

Comment: And then what? but this is totally offtopic

Comment: tell me why? what is the reason?  im asking same question in another stack and they +1 to me and ask it here -1 and close my question? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/42987

Comment: because each site has different rules.it is clearly explained in the reason for closing the question.

Comment: which reason? i seeking for module that exist there! but here no one know that exist. they think this is impossible . but this is exist there and works properly .

Comment: it is impossible. why do you ask a question when you know the answer better then anybody else

Comment: First version of my question only ask about the thing that i dont know after close i edit it and say this is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find a Wordpress plugin to do that - you need to use http://www.copyscape.com or something similar; Good luck getting people to remove your content though, most of them will be automatically generated heaps of junk.

Comment: i install that plugin in my wordpress site and register there and give api key and set it. how this work? email to me? when someone duplicate?

Comment: tell me why? what is the reason?  im asking same question in another stack and they +1 to me and ask it here -1 and close my question? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/42987

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do not being Google. Can you imagine the amount of crawling and parsing you have to do with each post?

There is [61 million blogs using Wordpress](http://en.wordpress.com/stats/), [91 million using Tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com/about), more than two millions of posts daily.

Try to use [Google Alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts) and use a quoted unique piece of your content as query.

Comment: Fantastic idea, Google alerts are very powerful!

Comment: this is possible. also with google analytics also with google blogs search also with copyscape.com also with many other tools..

Comment: I mean in more or less real time. Imagine: meanwhile you get a notification about theft, Google already considered you as thief, because real thief's site has, for example, greater trust rank than yours. See video [how to manage authorship](http://youtu.be/FgFb6Y-UJUI).

Comment: ok thanks but  why a blog that copy one of my posts is higher than me in results?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking if there's a plugin strong enough to scan the entire internet for content that is like the content on your site and then notify you?

The issue is you'd have to have a super complex algorithm to scan and then have super powerful compute to run something like that over the internet.

Basically, no, there is not something like this unless you're talking about Google or Bing.

Comment: for example with Google Analytics and filters? and customize them ....?

Comment: No, Google Analytics will track information on your site, or a site with the tracking code loaded on. It won't track what all sites around the internet are doing and how they compare to your site.

Comment: this is possible. also with google analytics in custom report that sites listed in inbound traffic list filterd and this report email monthly. ... also with google blogs search also with copyscape.com also with many other tools..

Comment: Google Analytics reports contain those sites who are already pointing to yours. Links are what's making inbound traffic from them.

Comment: yes that is correct. i ask 2 different question here because i think about this that may someone copy and dont link to me. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/42987/21250   http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/42984/21250

Comment: tell me why? what is the reason?  im asking same question in another stack and they +1 to me and ask it here -1 and close my question? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/42987